# How to handle large amount of data from array of pointer struct faster in Golang?

Tags: arrays, string, csv, go, builder

- I want to create a CSV file from []*dto.Customer.
- Getting all values and convert each struct values into a single string & then push into an array.
- Finally write into string builder then convert into []byte.

Here is the function,

```
func generateCSV(customers []*dto.Customer) []byte {

    var csvData strings.Builder
    var srcFileArray []string

    header := []string{"created Time", "Reference Number", "Customer Name", "Mobile Number", "Area", "Payment Mode"}
    csvData.WriteString(strings.Join(header, ",") + "\n")

    for _, cust := range customers {
        record := formatTimeZone(cust.CreatedDate).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") + "," + cust.ReferenceID + "," + cust.Name + "," + cust.number + "," + cust.Area + "," + cust.Payment
        srcFileArray = append(srcFileArray, record)
    }

    csvData.WriteString(strings.Join(srcFileArray, "\n"))
    byteArray := []byte(csvData.String())

    return byteArray
}
```

The struct I'm using,

```
type Customer struct {
    Name          string      `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Number        string      `json:"number,omitempty" bson:"number,omitempty"`
    ReferenceID   string      `json:"referenceID,omitempty" bson:"referenceId,omitempty"`
    CreatedDate   time.Time   `json:"createdDate,omitempty" bson:"createdDate,omitempty"`
    Area          string      `json:"area,omitempty" bson:"area,omitempty"`
    Payment       string      `json:"payment,omitempty" bson:"payment,omitempty"`
}
```

- The problem is when am handling hundreds of thousands of data in customer array, it takes 2 minutes for forming the string. so, my request gets failed and showing 502 error.

How to do that in minimal time period?

- I tried to split the array into two half and then run both array in Go routines, but the data given from this is not in order.
- I want the data in same order from the array.

Comment: You should look for more scaleable way and return partial dat only from your HTTP server. 
If you will add more data (dto.Customer - where its coming from) maybe we can assist with lower level advices.

Comment: Your request may be timing out due to going so long without sending any data, because you build the entire thing in memory before sending any bytes to the client. Instead of using `strings.Builder` and constructing it all in memory, just use [`encoding/csv`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv) to wrap the ResponseWriter and stream the data to the client as it's processed. This will also significantly reduce your memory usage, which may itself improve performance.

Comment: @Adrian that is one part of the problem and probably the largest part of the problem, the other one is the incoming customers array. It is unknown where it is coming from but it is probably a safe bet it is a database. Loading half the database into memory is definitely part of the memory and performance hit, that data too should be streamed from wherever it is coming from. But as it is, there is not enough information in this question to be able to answer it.

Comment: @Gimby agreed - streaming straight from DB -> csv.Writer -> ResponseWriter one row at a time would be the most efficient.